# What is the command line to backup my /var/www/html files?

Tags: backup, limits, centos8

what is the best command line to backup my files ?

tar -czf /backup/backup.tar.gz /var/www/html

or

tar -czvf /backup/backup.tar.gz /var/www/html

and what are the difrences between this to ?

P.S.

```
# tar -czf /backup/backup.tar.gz /var/www/html tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
```

i got this error why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both commands produce the same archive. The only difference is second command will display on the screen the files and directories which are archived.

Comment: ok so i should use the first command then right ?

Comment: @JackDuldi, yes, if you want quiet work of program.

Comment: # tar -czf /backup/backup.tar.gz /var/www/html
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
 i got this error why ?

Comment: @JackDuldi, this is a warning, not error. This is option of GNU tar to help you extract the archive on different place

Comment: tar: /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/2020/02: file changed as we read it <- also i got this error what about this ?

Comment: @JackDuldi, someone upload file during archive creation. In such case select timeframe when you do not expect uploads. Or wait some time and update this file in archive

Comment: i am afraid there is no timeframe like this its a very active website and files are being create constantly images uploads

Comment: @JackDuldi, in such case grab those messages and after some time (5 minutes for example) update the archive with them

Comment: thank you for all the help